# conda before pip install

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda

Whenever I want to install a python package, I find the `pip install <package>` instructions on most of the sites / README.md documentation in github etc.

A colleague told me recently to try first a `conda install <package>` and if this fails (because the package is not available) to use the `pip install` process afterwards.

Is the try with the conda installation step really necessary / beneficial or can I just do the `pip install` directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on your use case. Conda does more than pip does. Conda was developed after pip because the Conda folks did not think pip did enough. It aims to handle library dependencies outside of the realm of python such as C libraries, R packages, or really anything with a wheel. as well as handling the python packages themselves. This is important because these packages do not have the standard setup.py in their source code, so python will not install them into the site-packages directory which is useful for easy importing.

It is important to note that you can't use pip and conda interchangeably, as conda has a different packaging format.

To answer your question succinctly: If you use one, I would stick to it for the entirety of whatever you are doing, and not use conda "until it doesn't work for something" and then just switch to pip for installations that conda can't handle. That is a super good way to get into trouble you can't explain.

My advice: if you are sticking to python and python only, use pip. If you are considering outside libraries that have value to your project, conda is a good option.

Comment: In case you are using conda and a given module is not available you could build it. https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tutorials/build-pkgs.html